# How to make UIImageView respect its superview.layer.mask

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, calayer

I have a `UIView` with `self.layer.mask` set to a `CAShapeLayer`.  If I add a `UILabel` as a subview, the `UILabel` is properly masked, but if I add a `UIImageView` the mask is ignored.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a property I need to set on the `UIImageView` to make it respect the superview mask?

I can get the result I want by setting the `self.layer.contents` of the `UIView` directly to the `CGImage` I want to display, instead of adding the `UIImageView` as a subview, but that only handles a single `UIImage`.

Comment: Masking a UIImageView is perfectly legal and is normal behavior. If it isn't working, you're doing something wrong. Show your code!

Comment: Could you show your code for what you intend to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing works perfectly well for a UIImageView, as this screen shot demonstrates:

[image]

That is a view with a CAShapeLayer (with an "oval" path) as its mask and a UIImageView as its subview.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the UIImageView frame was being adjusted to fall entirely within the visible region, so no clipping was apparent.  This was a change to some complicated existing code so I did not see this right away.

Comment: But you did not reveal that. Based on what you actually asked, my answer proved to you that your subview being a UIImageView had nothing to do with the issue and thus set you on the path.